# Update button is not showing for latest uploaded build on play store

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, google-play

When I make a release build using `sh ./gradlew assembleRelease`, that is working perfectly on the devices but when I make a .aab file for Play Store, using the command `sh ./gradlew bundleRelease` and after installing the build from play store, the app is crashing. and also play store is not showing **UPDATE** option for the latest uploaded build.
Here is my packagae.json

```sh
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.4"
```

Comment: Did you install the app from google play ?

Comment: Yes. Actually the previous build was created using ionic and the new one is from react native with same bundle configurations